# I can't upload a profile picture

Tags: php, file-upload

I click the submit button and nothing happens. Error div doesnt even appear.
What could it be?

perfil.php is the file where the next div is

HTML

```
<div id="upload_container" class="user_container profile">
    <div class="container"><a class="btn cerrar"><span class="icon close"></span></a></div>
        <div class="formulario">
            <form action="perfil.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h1>Selecciona una imagen</h1>
                <input type="file" id="profileImage" name="profileImage" required />
                <input type="submit" id="boton_perfil" name="boton_perfil" value="Subir" class="btn" />
                <?php DataBase::SubirImagen(); ?>
             </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

PHP

```
public static function SubirImagen(){
    if(isset($_POST["boton_perfil"])){
                if($_FILES['profileImage']['name']){
                    $mensaje = "";

                    if(!$_FILES['profileImage']['error']){
                        $dimensiones = getimagesize($_FILES['profileImage']['tmp_name']);
                        $width = $dimensiones[0];
                        $height = $dimensiones[1];

                        if($_FILES['profileImage']['type'] != 'image/jpg'){
                            $mensaje = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>El archivo debe tener extension .jpg</div></div></div>";
                        }

                        /*else if($width != 540 || $height != 540){
                            $mensaje = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>El archivo debe ser 540x540</div></div></div>";
                        }*/

                        else if($_FILES['profileImage']['size'] > (1024000)){
                            $valid_file = false;
                            $mensaje = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>La imagen pesa demasiado</div></div></div>";
                        }

                        else if($valid_file){
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileImage']['tmp_name'], "../database/usuarios/".$_SESSION["usuario"]."/user");
                            $mensaje = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Tu imagen ha sido actualizada</div></div></div>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        $mensaje = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Hubo un error".$_FILES['photo']['error']."</div></div></div>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks too much for your help. You're all welcome

Comment: You might want to try and echo $message or $mensaje?

Comment: enctype is missing in the <form>-tag

Comment: You might want to remove the use of the `@` error silencer as well. Test for errors **dont just ignore them** If `$_POST["boton_perfil"]` does not exist, yo dont want to run any of this code.

Comment: $_POST["boton_perfil"] is the submit button, how cant it exist

Comment: When is a button not a button ? _When it is not pressed_

Comment: `isset()` Thats better

Comment: It doesnt still work